# MagicalRecord: modify attribute of related object

Tags: ios, json, core-data, relationship, magicalrecord

I am importing a JSON response from a webservice I don't control. This response contains elements that I mapped to a `Show` entity that has multiple related `Artwork` objects in the same JSON.

I set up the relationship via the userinfo keys and that's working well. My problem is that the artwork elements in the JSON do not contain a unique id:

```
    {
        Filetype = jpg;
        Id = "-1036406380";
        Offset = 2;
        Rating = 1;
        Type = 3;
    }
```

There may be multiple elements with the same `Id`. This will result in MagicalRecord not recognizing those elements if they are already stored in CoreData.

My solution was to introduce a new field on the entity called uniqueArtworkID. This field would be a string concatenated by ID, Offset and Type.

Finally the question:
How or at what point in the code can I create the uniqueArtworkID so that MagicalRecord is able to pick that up as the "primary" key for the Artwork entity?

Edit:
I found out that I can override `- (BOOL) MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:(id)objectData` in my NSManagedObject subclass to generate and set the unique id. One step closer, but that doesn't solve the problem that the original JSON data doesn't contain that unique key and checks for existing objects fail, resulting in duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by dropping MagicalRecord and using the Core Data API directly.